# Is it possible to name a constant a protected word in PHP?

Tags: php, naming-conventions, constants

In C#, variables and other things can be named protected names such as "class" by prepending the name with an @ sign. So, @class is a valid name. Is it possible to do this same thing in PHP? I am using a class of constants to simulate an enum for HTML attributes such as ID, and Class. For now I am using "CssClass" but I'd rather use the name Class somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, [not possible](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php), at least not for class constants.

> You cannot use any of the following [reserved] words as constants, class names, function or method names.

I don't know about C#, but there isn't any special symbol in PHP to transform a keyword into an identifier. As long as you don't name it exactly the same as a keyword (barring letter case), it'll just be any normal constant name.

How about a (different since it's not just CSS) prefix? Gets repetitive to type, but is a nice workaround. I realize this may be redundant as well if your class is named something like `HTMLAttribute`, but it's the easiest way out.

```
const A_ID = 'id';
const A_CLASS = 'class';
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm stuck with Attr::CssClass or Attr::_Class

Comment: bizarrely enough, this works: https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/7fcf997c6e50a6fad048eceb3eea71b8
only class fails, any other reserved word seems to work fine (on PHP 7 at least)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it is possible.

In fact you can define anything as constant:

```
define("define", 1);
define("class", 1);
define("if", 1);
define("=.+*", 1);
```

However, you can **not** *use* all defined constants.

You can query them with `constant("if")` again. But this is not exactly what you asked for. So unlike C# there is no shortcut to use any random constant. But as for naming them, there are almost no restrictions. (Might be a bug though. It's PHP.)

Comment: Not possible for class constants though, as there is no runtime function to define class constants.

Comment: @BoltClock actually runkit_constant_add() should be able to. But that's even less senseful, since it will be *more* difficult to read such wacky constants out again.

Comment: Ahhh, I tend to forget about runkit most of the time.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think it's for the best if we all agree to avoid it ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php):

> The name of a constant follows the same rules as any label in PHP. A valid constant name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thusly: `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`

[List of reserved keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php):

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on--but they're not, really: they are language constructs. **You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method name.**
>
> [[see list here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)]

Within these rules you're free to make up your names. So, for instance, you could name a constant `_CLASS`, but not `CLASS`. I'd avoid the use of such ambiguous names though and namespace constants that are particular to the app, like `MYAPP_CLASS`.

Answer (score 0):

Going from PHP5 to PHP7, a class constant could be named almost anything:

```
class ReservedWord
{
    // Works in PHP >= 7.0 only
    const NULL = null;
    const TRUE = true;
}
```

However, thanks to [this part of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php) and [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php#110244), I've found that a class constant cannot be named these few things (see the test [here](https://3v4l.org/rn0se)):

1. `class`
2. `static`
3. `__halt_compiler` (oh, that was so useful!)

**Edit**: As I found in [here in an RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/context_sensitive_lexer#limitations), the reason why `class` constant does not work is the name resolution `::class`. However, still no idea about the two others.