# Is constant name DEFAULT not allowed in PHP?

Tags: php, constants

I'm getting an error when I try to define a constant named `DEFAULT`. Why is this?

```
<?php
define('DEFAULT', true);
var_dump(DEFAULT);
// or
class Test {
    const DEFAULT = true;
}
var_dump(Test::DEFAULT);
```

This results in the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'DEFAULT' (T_DEFAULT) in ... on line X

Comment: `default` is used in `switch` and it's reserved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not allowed, because `DEFAULT` or `default` (case doesn't matter) is a reserved word. It is used in `switch` blocks:

```
switch( $x )
{
    case 1: echo $x; break;
    case 2: echo $x; break;
    case 3: echo $x; break;
    default: echo $x; break;
}
```

[Here is a list](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php) of the reserved words in PHP.

Comment: That's pretty involved just to `echo $x` ;-)

Answer (score 8):

`default` is a reserved language keyword in PHP. It is used for the default option in a `switch` block.

So no, you can't use it in a `define` statement.

Answer (score 4):

People write here that `default` is a reserved word and you should not use and etc - and it's true. But you still can access constant named `'DEFAULT'` with [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function:

```
define('DEFAULT', 'Some value');
var_dump(constant('DEFAULT'));
```

Going further: you can name constants as you like, even

```
define('#1', 'Number ONE');
define('-100', 'Hundred!');
define('while', 'It is WHILE!');
```

The problem is that `php` will treat this constants' names in code not how you expect.
That's why I (and other programmers) **not recommend** you to use such approach.

Comment: Wow, I did not know you could do that! Nice of you to point that out :)
    But it's better to find a different name for the constant XD

Comment: Just because there is a workaround for something, doesn't mean you should use it to force something. There is a reason why you would need a workaround to enforce your ideals. Not recommending is an understatement in this case. It should or even must be avoided at all.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.  It is a reserved Keyword.  You can find this in the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

On the keyword page you will find this information:

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things
>   which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but
>   they're not, really: they are language constructs. You cannot use any
>   of the following words as constants, class names, function or method
>   names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to
>   confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with PHP 7.0, it is allowed to be used, but only as a *class constant*.

So your first example is not allowed in any version of PHP, but the second example is allowed in PHP 7.

See an example: https://3v4l.org/8Hi3W

Comment: It still throws the same syntax error… https://3v4l.org/0Mo5u Any reference to back up this claim?

Comment: It works in PHP 7.0 and higher if you define it with `const`: https://3v4l.org/8Hi3W

Comment: *If you also namespace it in a class,* okay. Big qualifier there.

Comment: However, there are very few restrictions. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081053/4215651).